# injecting named service in JAX-RS resource by constructor with OpenEJB

Tags: jax-rs, cdi, openejb

I'm using OpenEJB as application server and I want to deploy a Jax-RS resource that requires some named service to be injected in its constructor.

My resource looks like :

```
@Singleton
@Path("/")
public class Resource {

    private Service service;

    @Inject
    public Resource(@Named("service") Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, OpenEJB complains because it doesn't consider my constructor to be valid because of the @Named annotation decorating the Service argument.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource class class test.Resource has no valid constructor
at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CdiResourceProvider.validateConstructorExists(CdiResourceProvider.java:138)
at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CdiResourceProvider.<init>(CdiResourceProvider.java:100)
at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.OpenEJBPerRequestPojoResourceProvider.<init>(OpenEJBPerRequestPojoResourceProvider.java:28)
at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication(CxfRsHttpListener.java:522)
```

The implementation of the OpenEJB CdiResourceProvider clearly doesn't want something else than the Jax-RS @Context annotation for constructor arguments...
Is it supported by OpenEJB?

Answer (score 1):

JAX-RS has a specific requirement for a no-args constructor.  This will be true of any JAX-RS impl, its not specific to the OpenEJB integration.